# How to get name of json object with angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I am trying to get name of json object (`bdev0`, and `bdev1` in this case) from my dataset.

So far I have tried ng-options with no success. What I am trying to achieve in the following code is just to retrieve the name of json object. So far all the examples I have tried did not work for my case.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3822/)

Code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
        "Block_Devices": {
            "bdev0": {
                "Backend_Device_Path": "/dev/ram1",
                "Capacity": "16777216",
                "Bytes_Written": 1577,
                "timestamp": "4365093970",
                "IO_Operations": 17757,
                "Guest_Device_Name": "vdb",
                "Bytes_Read": 17793,
                "Guest_IP_Address": "192.168.26.88"
            },
            "bdev1": {
                "Backend_Device_Path": "/dev/ram2",
                "Capacity": "16777216",
                "Bytes_Written": 1975,
                "timestamp": "9365093970",
                "IO_Operations": 21380,
                "Guest_Device_Name": "vdb",
                "Bytes_Read": 20424,
                "Guest_IP_Address": "192.168.26.100"
            }
        },
        "Number of Devices": 2
    }]

}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select name="Block_Devices" ng-model="selectedDevice"  ng-options="value.Block_Devices for value in data">
  <option value="">Please Select Device</option>
    </select>
</div>
Selected Device = {{selectedDevice}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `ng-repeat="(key, value) in array"` syntax.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data[0].Block_Devices">
{{key}}
</div>
```

{{key}} will be the property of Block_Devices 
See sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hj9gzbrL/)

Comment: ng-options="key for (key, value) in data[0].Block_Devices" will work in select

Answer (score 1):

As Bon stated before me you can do as in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8r5318yv/)

```
  <select name="Block_Devices" ng-model="selectedDevice.Bytes_Written" ng-options="key for (key, value) in data[0].Block_Devices">
    <option value="">Please Select Device</option>
  </select>
```